# Bar heater operating on a duty cycle - possible problems?

Tags: electrical-engineering

It's easy to obtain a room-scale radiant heater (of the order of 700-800W per bar, eg [this three-bar heater](http://www.goldair.com.au/product-catalogue/heating/radiant-heaters/2400w-3-bar-radiant-heater-gir335)) that operates very simply and easily - you turn it on, it consumes electricity, it generates heat. Convenient, cheap, simple. But they don't seem to be made in lower wattages, and my inexpert brain is wondering: what would happen if one of these were to have some electronics added to run it only part of the time? For instance, let's say I selected 75% power on one bar; it would close the circuit for 750ms, then cut the power for 250ms, repeat indefinitely.

Are there any critical downsides to a system like this?

Would this actually consume (roughly) 75% of the power and produce 75% of the heat, or would something in the behaviour of this kind of heating element change this?

Why don't heaters like this exist, with full option for any power level you choose?

Comment: Works great. Starts at about 100 dollars, which is a bit of a stretch for a 10 dollar heater. Google SCR Power Control.

Comment: Can you post a bit more detail, preferably including a reference showing it to be functional (doesn't matter if it's not commercially viable) for this sort of heater? I'd happily accept that as an answer.

Comment: See my answer to a [related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/253158/73158) over on Electronics.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Electric heaters are `LR circuit` Inductance and resistance, controlling heaters with operation duty cycle will be far expensive then using simple use a high `LR coil`. switching controlled power supply will introduce skips or surge voltage into the supply line. hence not advisable. more power switching mean more surges. Moreover various county has certain government regulation around it to lower inductive loads by adding parallel capacitors.

off-topic note for enthusiast : In terms of fluid mechanics it is called Hydraulic shock